# How to check if a particular node is present in XML in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I want to check if a node is present under a specific node, it can be present in any level. (It can be deeper).

For this XML:

```
<main>
  <sub>
    <inner>
      <first></first>
      <second></second>
    </inner>
  </sub>
</main>
```

How do I check to see whether the `sub` node has an inner node `first` or not, using Nokogiri without using the XPath `'/sub/inner'` directly?

Comment: How about XPath `sub//first`? that will check/return `first` node within `sub` no matter how deep `first` is nested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XPath isn't correct unless you know that your `sub` node is at the top level. Think of XPath selectors as paths in an OS. `/sub` would be at the root of the drive.

I'd recommend using CSS selectors for clarity:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<main>
  <sub>
    <inner>
      <first>first_text</first>
      <second></second>
    </inner>
  </sub>
</main>
EOT

doc.at('sub first').text # => "first_text"
```

`'sub first'` means that `first` has to exist somewhere under `'sub'`.

This might help:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<main>
  <sub>
    <inner>
      <first>first_text</first>
      <second></second>
    </inner>
  </sub>
</main>
EOT

doc.at('/sub/first') # => nil
doc.at('sub first') # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd580c9e54c name="first" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd580c9e2f4 "first_text">]>
doc.at('//sub/*/first') # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd580c9e54c name="first" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd580c9e2f4 "first_text">]>
doc.at('//sub//first') # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd580c9e54c name="first" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd580c9e2f4 "first_text">]>

doc.at('sub first').text # => "first_text"
doc.at('//sub/*/first').text # => "first_text"
doc.at('//sub//first').text # => "first_text"
```